# DRF-Haystack SearchIndex returning from ALL index classes?

Tags: elasticsearch, django-rest-framework, django-haystack

I'm using haystack with elasticsearch backend in django, and drf-haystack to implement serializers for results.

I first created a StudentIndex, which indexes over StudentProfiles to use in searches for students in **search_indexes.py**

```
class StudentIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(
        document=True,
        use_template=True,
        template_name="search/indexes/user_search_text.txt")

    //other indexes or indices or whatever

    def get_model(self):
        return StudentProfile

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        return StudentProfile.objects.filter(user__is_active=True)
```

Which is passed to the serializer and viewset in **views.py**:

```
class StudentSerializer(HaystackSerializer):

    class Meta:
        index_classes = [StudentIndex]


class StudentSearchView(ListModelMixin, HaystackGenericAPIView):
    index_models = [StudentProfile]
    serializer_class = StudentSerializer
    pagination_class = None

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

and everything was fine and dandy....UNTIL I added two more indexes over other profiles and a single view/serializer to handle them. All exist in the same respective files:
**search_indexes.py**

```
class TeacherIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(
        document=True,
        use_template=True,
        template_name="search/indexes/user_search_text.txt")

    //other indexes or indices or whatever

    def get_model(self):
        return TeacherProfile

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        return TeacherProfile.objects.filter(user__is_active=True)

class StaffIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(
        document=True,
        use_template=True,
        template_name="search/indexes/user_search_text.txt")

    //other indexes or indices or whatever

    def get_model(self):
        return StaffProfile

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        return StaffProfile.objects.filter(user__is_active=True)
```

and added to **views.py**:

```
class StaffSerializer(HaystackSerializer):

    class Meta:
        index_classes = [StaffIndex, TeacherIndex]


class StaffSearchView(ListModelMixin, HaystackGenericAPIView):
    index_models = [StaffProfile, TeacherProfile]
    serializer_class = StaffSerializer
    pagination_class = None

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

NOW....each view goes to its own url endpoint (/student-search and /staff-search respectively), but ONLY the staff-search endpoint properly returns Staff and TeacherProfile results, while the student-search, in a seperate endpoint with seperate view and models and indexes all explicitly stated, is return StudentProfiles AND Teacher and StaffProfiles and I can not for the life of me figure out why.

If anyone has run into this before, I'd really appreciate help solving, and more importantly, understanding, this issue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: UPDATE: I've tried adding new Haystack connections, "student" and "staff", which student having

    'EXCLUDED_INDEXES': [
                'search.search_indexes.StaffIndex',
                'search.search_indexes.TeacherIndex',
            ]

Staff ignores StudentIndex and still functions properly

The student search is STILL returning teacher and staff profiles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, for future people with the same issues, here's all i needed to do to solve it.

I'm using the DRF-Haystack genericviewapi, and on the view, I simply defined the filter_queryset to use the proper haystack connection (which ignored other indices). So for example:

```
class StudentSearchView(ListModelMixin, HaystackGenericAPIView):
    index_models = [StudentProfile]
    serializer_class = StudentSerializer
    pagination_class = None

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def filter_queryset(self, queryset):
        queryset = super(HaystackGenericAPIView, self).filter_queryset(queryset)
        return queryset.using('student')
```

Everything now works properly :)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, but when i use the `queryset.using('dynamic')`, it raises `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured`: The key 'dynamic' isn't an available connection.

```
class DynamicSearchView(ListModelMixin, HaystackGenericAPIView):

    serializer_class = serializers.DynamicSearchSerializer
    filter_backends = [HaystackHighlightFilter]

    @swagger_auto_schema(
        manual_parameters=[text, type]
    )
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def filter_queryset(self, queryset):
        return super(DynamicSearchView, self).filter_queryset(queryset).using('dynamic')
```

Comment: I did not define the index_model..., so foolish :)